# What to select for "type of source" for a paper in Microsoft Word?

Tags: citations

I am currently doing my very first paper at university and am a bit lost with Word’s citation system.
What does a scientific paper (more specifically [this one](http://etclab.mie.utoronto.ca/publication/1994/Milgram_Takemura_SPIE1994.pdf)) classify as when it comes to “type of source” in Word?

[image: picture of dropdown for type of source picker]

This probably is a very simple question, but I am really having trouble finding an answer.
Here’s an explanation of my thought process:

- It is certainly not a book nor a book section.
- I don’t feel like it would count as an article in a journal or peridocal as from my understanding research papers are published as a stand-alone?
- Conference Proceeding: I have no idea what that is, but I think it isn’t it.
- Maybe a report? As it reports on findings that were made ... but I feel this is also not quite right ...
- It is not a website.
- I might use *document from website*, however this paper is available on several websites (at least through my Google Scholar search) that seem to have picked it up, however it was not originally published through them from what I can tell.
- While I have it as a PDF, I don't think that is meant by **electronic source.*
- Art: no
- Sound Recording: no
- Performance: no
- Film: no
- Interview: no
- Patent: no
- I have no idea what is meant by *case.* As in a lawsuit?
- *Misc* is what I will pick for now, but I guess citing research papers in a scientific work isn’t something happening so seldomly that one would have to resort to *misc.*

Comment: I **strongly** recommend against using Microsoft Word for paper writing. Yes, it’s widely used. No, it’s not good at it. — If you’re comfortable with it, author your paper in LaTeX, Pandoc-Scholar or similar. If you’re not comfortable with it, at least use a proper collaborative editing system like Google Docs. — More to the point, *do not* use Word’s integrated citation system. Use a proper reference manager software. It will save you a lot of pain.

Comment: @KonradRudolph While true, some journals/etc. prefer Word as the format, by my understanding.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: TBH, besides the collaborative aspect - which can indeed be a strong plus -, Google Docs is quite ridiculous in typesetting capabilities, lacking features that were available on Word 6 for Windows 3.1 (one for all that left me baffled: custom styles). I wouldn't use it for anything moderately serious.

Comment: @MatteoItalia In my experience, paper writing doesn’t require most of these features. Personally I agree though: custom styles (and line intermittent numbers!) are crucial features for paper writing. But my former collaborators don’t seem to miss (or indeed, ever have used) these features. Incidentally, I’m not a huge fan of Pandoc-Scholar/Markdown/etc for the same reason. Just use LaTeX already.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: indeed most people I've ever seen using a word processor don't seem to know much besides "hard formatting" (and [WordArt](https://makewordart.com/) in the glorious days), so I see your point. It just makes me sad that a tool that could have so much potential is - as often happens - half-assed enough to be surpassed in useful features by 25 years old software. :-(

Comment: @MatteoItalia well normally I like to use InDesign for longer texts as I love it’s style capabilities, but since this is the first time writing a paper for our course we are supposed to do it in groups and therefore I deemed word to be the easiest as it has collaboration features without requiring version control that will probably just irritate my fellow students. For what I do word has been sufficient. I probably won’t write that many papers in my life, so for now I guess I will be faster with word than learning LaTex from scratch :D

Comment: To pile on a little bit: I won't argue one way or the other about using Word to write papers, but I would recommend that you try a separate bibliographic database system/organizer such as [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/); it has lots of advantages, one being that your references won't be locked in Word if you decide to switch writing platforms.

Comment: @CrazyQwert You're wise to use the same tool as your collaborators. Good luck with your paper!

Comment: @BenBolker Zotero looks quite cool indeed!

Comment: @CrazyQwert Although most people are familiar with word, collaborating with them in LaTeX is possible: services like https://www.overleaf.com/ provide it is a webapp so no one has to install anything and even offer the capability to edit in rich text (similar to Google docs). So, you can work with all the features of LaTeX you want while your collaborators can work in an as simple rich text environment as they want.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The paper you link is *not* a journal article. It's published as part of a conference proceedings.

You can find the complete proceedings in which that paper appears [here](https://spie.org/Publications/Proceedings/Volume/2351?SSO=1) (link is to the SPIE page for the 1994 conference Telemanipulators and Telepresence Technologies).

To address some other points in your question, I cannot think of a legitimate research paper that was *not* published in a journal or conference. Publishing in this sense means putting the paper through peer review, an essential part of contributing to the literature if you want your work to be taken seriously.

Furthermore, conference proceedings are exactly what it says on the tin: proceedings (i.e. talks) from a conference that have been written up and published. Publishing in this way is more common in some fields than others, for example, in computer science, just like the paper you linked.

Comment: Depending on field, recent work *might* appear on a preprint server such as the arxiv up to a year or more before it passes peer review. In an extreme case where a student has moved on to other pastures, that might be the only easily citable version of the work available.

Comment: One standard set of examples of extremely legitimate research papers that were never published in a journal or conference proceedings are Perelman's groundbreaking works that won him a Millennium Prize and a Fields Medal.